# if doesn't work in python3

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.6

I am making a program that helps with things, such as math
but something is weird. When I type "help me with math", it does nothing and
just says "i don't know". this is python 3.6 on windows.
something is weird.

```
import pymsgbox
def alert(text='',title='',timeout=None):
    pymsgbox.alert(text=text,title=title,timeout=timeout)
def prompt(text='',title='',timeout=None):
    pymsgbox.prompt(text=text,title=title,timeout=timeout)
def math():
    eq=prompt("do you need an equation done?(y,n)")

    eqat=str(prompt(text="enter the equation:"))
    e=eval(eqat)
    alert(text="the awnser is: "+str(e))
prompts={"i dom't know.":"Well, i have nothing to do for you!",}
while True:
    alert(text="this is an helper for stuff.",title="helper")
    inp =prompt(text="how can i help you?",title="helper")
    if inp=="Help me with math":
        math()
    if inp in prompts:
        anwser=prompts[inp]
        alert(text=awnser)
    else:
        alert(text="i don't know how to help you.")
```

Comment: what you are typing doesn't appear to have a capital H

Comment: You even state in your problem description that you don't write the same string you check for

Comment: Also, `alert(text=prompts.get(inp, 'i don't know how to help you.'))` would help solve the typo in the variable name and remove 4 lines of code.

Comment: An aside, there is no tax applied to the number of lines in your script or spaces. Please look up PEP8 and space your code out to make it more legible.

Comment: You're giving the wrong awnser(sic!).

Answer (score 0):

You should type "Help me with math" instead of "help me with math". 
Those are different strings, letter case matters.

Comment: and if you dont want case to matter, try [str.lower()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower)